# Create mock service returning flat files

Tags: unit-testing, flat-file, messagebroker, extended-sql

I need to build a message flow where I am supposed to trigger a message(which is combination of numbers and alphabets simply a Id no) to a URL through HTTP request node and get a flat file in response(EDI Data). I have coded and I want to test whether my flow is working.

For this I need to create a mock service and construct a flat file. My question is how I can construct the response. Any proper code to write flat files(EDI data) so that I can get that as response and make sure my flow is working.

---

**This is how exactly my response should look like:**

```
EDI_BA40   125566  INVOIC LS 0036566
```

.......... and so on

---

Please provide some solution so that I can receive this in my response or something that I can do to test my flow so that there would be no error when I move my code next environment(QAL/PRD).

Comment: I think the easiest way is to create another flow which can return prerecorded responses.

Comment: Thank you Attila for your response, can you describe more how to do this.  Actually the response we would be getting only if the HTTP response header status is 200, and I think we will get status 200 only when we do the mocking.please Kindly correct my concepts If I am wrong and provide some solution.

Comment: Create another flow with HTTPInput and HTTPReply, and a Compute to set your desired response, with the needed response headers. You can call this flow to test your original flow.